# Liquid Fire and Unclogging Bathtub - lingering residue

Tags: acid-base

So my mom needed help with a bathtub drain that wasn't performing all that well. She sent me out to the hardware store to get some Drain-o, but they didn't carry that brand.  Instead, the young man helping me suggested this brand of drain opener called Liquid Fire.  Said that it will unclog the pipes real quick. I took his word for it and began to get checked out when the owner of the shop, an elder fellow who had been running the hardware store before I was even born, took one look at the product and gave one of those short whistles.  He said it was some potent stuff and to not be in the room after I poured it, to keep the door closed and window opened in the bathroom, and then to let it sit for about 10-15 mins before running hot water in the shower for another 15 mins.  Ok, can do.

I kept his directions in mind, took note that I was working with sulfuric acid, so wore gloves, even a respirator just in case. I poured the acid down the drain then closed the door behind me and waited.  Definitely got the rotten egg smell. After about 20 mins, I came back and there was this mass of brown residue all over the tub.  Not just around the drain, but it streaked all the way to the back, and even up the sides like the tub had been filled up about 6 inches. I didn't touch it, but decided to run the water and see what happened.  Came back after 15 mins, the rotten egg smell had dispersed some, but the residue was still there.  After running some more water to make sure all the acid had washed away, my mom had me throw comet over all the stain and we were able to scrub the residue off.

So my question is, does this normally happen with a tub drain and liquid fire? As in, the tub fills up and then drains back out leaving a residue. And if not, was this some kind of eruption and what caused it?  And what was this brown residue (debris, rust, etc.)?

Comment: A great deal of heat is generated when concentrated sulfuric acid is diluted, even more when it interacts with organic matter. This is certainly enough to boil the water in the pipework driving the brown residue back up the line.

Comment: Foam did this. You should have covered the drain with an upturned pot, then it wouldn't spread that wide. Then again, it's not a big deal.